# How to dynamically generate checkboxes on the view and submit to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I send a collection to my view and iterate over it.  Each iteration has a checkbox as well as two text fields.  I want to be able to submit selected items, but also submit the values in the text field as an update as well.

```
<% @lots.each_with_index do |lot, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= lot.lot_code  %></td>
      <td ><%= check_box_tag "lots[][lot_id]", lot.id, false, %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "lots[][seal_num]", lot.seal_number %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "lots[][contr_num]", lot.container_number %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

My `@lots` collection has three rows:

```
{id: 2, container_number: "container#0002", seal_number: "seal#0002"}
{id: 6, container_number: "container#0006", seal_number: "seal#0006"}
{id: 11, container_number: "container#00011", seal_number: "seal#00011"}
```

(apologies if that is not proper hash syntax)

My problem is that if I check items 1 and 3, the parameter string shows the following:

```
"lots"=>[{"lot_id"=>"2", "seal_num"=>"seal 0002", "contr_num"=>"container#0002"}, 
{"seal_num"=>"Seal-006", "contr_num"=>"container #006", "lot_id"=>"11"}, 
{"seal_num"=>"Seal-0011", "contr_num"=>"container #0011"}]
```

The problem is that `lot_id = 11` should be the 3rd item in the array, not the second.  For some reason, because item #2 is not selected, the empty `lot_id` element is being populated by the next one in the sequence.

How do I make sure the selected IDs are in the same elements as the other attributes?  Or how do I make sure the non-selected items don't even end up on the parameter string?

Edit:  I have also tried the following:

```
<% @lots.each_with_index do |lot, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= lot.lot_code  %></td>
      <td ><%= check_box_tag "lots[#{index}][lot_id]", lot.id, false, %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "lots[#{index}][seal_num]", lot.seal_number %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "lots[#{index}][contr_num]", lot.container_number %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

And I get this on the following parameter string:

```
lots"=>{"0"=>{"lot_id"=>"2", "seal_num"=>"seal 0002", "contr_num"=>"container#0002"}, 
"1"=>{"seal_num"=>"Seal-006", "contr_num"=>"container #006"}, 
"2"=>{"lot_id"=>"19", "seal_num"=>"Seal-0011", "contr_num"=>"container #0011"}}
```

This maintains the integrity of the rows as desired, but I later get a "TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer" later on in processing.

Edit 2:  Realized the solution in the edit created a hash, and my code was looking to access an array.  So when the hash was iterated over, I was errantly accessing the key, an integer, rather than the value.

Comment: if the last solution works well for you why are you not investigating the reason for -  "TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer" error? maybe you just have some trivial issue and you need to fix it? Can you provide an example of a code which you using for later processing?

Comment: Since posting, I have found the source of the TypeError:  the latter solution created a hash rather than an array, and I was using `each` to iterate through it in my controller.  I was looking at the key rather than the value.